# Web3.js Script exits while listening to CreatedPairs

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am trying to create a simple script to test the event listening functionality of Web3.js `CreatedPairs`. However, my script runs through the code once and then exits instead of continuing to listen for created pairs and I cannot figure out why.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'https://mynodeishere');

const IUniswapV2Factory = require("@uniswap/v2-core/build/IUniswapV2Factory.json")
const UNI_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f'
const uFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(IUniswapV2Factory.abi, UNI_FACTORY_ADDRESS)


const main = async () => {

    // Create event listener to listen to PairCreated
    uFactory.events.PairCreated({}, async (error, event) => {
    
        console.log(`New pair detected...\n`)

    })
}

main()
```

What ends up happening is when I run `node ./myapp.js`. The code gets stepped in to and logs `New pair detected...` to the console and then exits. This happening right away tells me that it is not executing when a new pair is detected and is instead just stepping through the code.

However, what I anticipated happening was for the app to continue to run and log to the console only when a new pair is detected. I am sure I am overlooking something small, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up solving my issue was realizing that I was not using a `WebService` Provider. I was able to fix this by using the `wss` version of my `node` connection.

```
// example connection to a WSS provider
const web3 = new Web3('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<mytoken>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
const options = {
    fromBlock:  'latest'
};

uFactory.events.PairCreated(options)
    .on('data', event => console.log(event))
```

use WebSocket provider instead of HTTP provider since it doesn't support subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for the response. It would appear that your changes are not stepping in to the call back at all now. I have watched multiple pairs get created and have gotten no logs to the console. One difference is that for the `fromBlock` parameter I decided to use `latest`. Any ideas?