# Get Return value back from smart contract function

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am using     `"web3": "^1.5.1",` and `"web3-eth-contract": "^1.5.2"`.

I have the following solidity function in my contract:

```
    function mint(string memory _linkURL) public payable returns (uint) {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        uint256 tokenID = supply + 1;

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            require(msg.value >= cost);
        }

        emit Logging(_linkURL);
        setLinkURL(_linkURL);

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenID);

        return tokenID;
    }
```

As you can see I am writing an url to the function before minting the token. In my app I do this the following way:

```
    const claimNFTs = () => {
        let cost = CONFIG.WEI_COST; // how much does the rNFT service cost
        let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
        let totalCostWei = String(cost * mintAmount);
        let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount);
        let currentUrl = window.location.href;
        console.log("Current URL: " + currentUrl);
        console.log("Cost: ", totalCostWei);
        console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
        setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
        setClaimingNft(true);
        blockchain.smartContract.methods
            .mint(currentUrl)
            .send({
                gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
                to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
                from: blockchain.account,
                value: totalCostWei,
            })
            .once("error", (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                setFeedback("Sorry, something went wrong please try again later.");
                setClaimingNft(false);
            })
            .then((receipt) => {
                console.log(receipt);
                setFeedback(
                    `WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit Opensea.io to view it.`
                );
                setClaimingNft(false);
                dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
            });
    };
```

Any suggestions how to get the `tokenID` as a return value from the contract? Is there another parameter that I should get back via the promise?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You can listen to this specific event for this specific user

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa Thx for your reply! How would this look like? Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some details, like which events are emitted, but in a nutshell it should look like this.
First of all, you need set your filter to get the event for your specific event.

```
let options = {
    filter: {
        (your indexed params),
        receiver: 0xabc... (example)

    },
    fromBlock: 0 (better to start from the block where you've deploy your contract, better to have a `rpc node` with `archive mode`)
};


smartContract.events.Mint(options)
    .on('data', event => console.log(event))
    .on('changed', changed => console.log(changed))
    .on('error', err => throw err)
    .on('connected', str => console.log(str))
```

similar questions:
[Web3.js Script exits while listening to CreatedPairs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124349/web3-js-script-exits-while-listening-to-createdpairs/124357#124357)

[Default options for getPastEvents in web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124602/default-options-for-getpastevents-in-web3js/124615#124615)

web3 doc for events:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id36

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html

Comment: Thx. The event is called `Logging`

Comment: ok replace `Mint` with Logging, and add all the required indexed filters